# How do I access the pointer in this struct correctly?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Below are definitions for 2 structs, then a short method body that uses them.
I don't understand why the compiler throws the error:

> physics.c:95: error: incompatible types in assignment

`cpBody` and `cpSpace` are types from an external library, which isn't part of the problem.

```
typedef struct gameBody gameBody;

struct gameBody
{
    cpBody *body;
    int numberOfShapes;
    cpShape *arrayOfShapes; //This stores an array of pointers to Shapes
};

//Struct that stores the cpSpace object and the array of pointers to the body objects
typedef struct gameSpace gameSpace;

struct gameSpace
{ 
    cpSpace *space;
    int numberOfObjects;
    gameBody *arrayOfObjects;       //This stores an array of gameBodys
};

void physicsAddBody(gameSpace *space, gameBody *body, int objectIndex)
{
    gameBody *array = space -> arrayOfObjects;
    array[objectIndex] = body; //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS THROWN
}
```

Comment: array[objectIndex] = body;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> array[objectIndex] = body;

On the left side is a `gameBody`, on the right side a `gameBody*`.

Do you try to copy the struct or do you want to assign the pointer into a pointer-array?

Comment: thanks, i was wondering if you could help me out with a line that was throwing the same error:

    gameBody *gBody = space -> arrayOfObjects[i];

Comment: @nope:  you have to be careful because there are 2 very different operations: (A) if you assign a struct to a struct then the data in that struct will be copied (B) if you assign a pointer to a struct into a pointer-array only pointers are involved.

Comment: @nope it depends on which one you mean. Is the second argument to `physicsAddBody` a pointer to a single gameBody or is it the array?

Answer (score 0):

Your last line should be:

```
array[objectIndex] = *body;
```

because body is not a gameBody but a pointer to a gameBody.

(and I hope you have allocated the memory somewhere...)

Comment: thanks, i was wondering if you could help me out with a line that was throwing the same error: gameBody *gBody = space -> arrayOfObjects[i];

and yes memory was allocated, wouldn't want a segfault would we?

Comment: gameBody *gBody = &(space->arrayOfObjects[i]) 
or, which is the same:
gBody = space->arrayOfObjects + i